# Where do I find system-ca-bundle.crt on OSX?

Tags: mono

I'm running mono 4.8 and have some trouble with certificates. I know I need to run `cert-sync` but I can't figure out where the `system-ca-bundle.crt` is on OSX. The docs for this release, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/, only mentions where it is on different linux systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the complete Mozilla CA certificate store in PEM format from:

- https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Buyer beware: Downloading and blindly adding CA Root Certificates should set off bells, alarms, and whistles. The `cacert.pem` they provide is `SHA256` marked and you can compare it to Mozilla's

- https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/raw-file/default/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt

That said, you can always extract the individual CA certs you need from that PEM and verify each one, etc.... Or blindly add them all:

```
curl --remote-name --time-cond cacert.pem https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
cert-sync --user cacert.pem
```

Set `BoringSSL` as Mono's TLS provider and enjoy:

```
export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls
```

Comment: The important part was to use `--user` which I forgot.